# Independent random variables - Finding $P(X = Y )$ and $P(X ≤ Y )$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables in a probability space $(\Omega, P)$ with the following distributions:
>
> [image: table]
>
> Calculate:
>
> (a) $P(X = Y ),$
>
> (b) $ P(X ≤ Y ).$

Can you please check my solutions? I have the following:

(a) $P(X = Y )= 0.20 \cdot 0.15 + 0.36 \cdot 0.26 + 0.26 \cdot 0.37 + 0.18 \cdot0.22 = 0.2584.$

(b) $ P(X ≤ Y )= P( X = Y) + P (x < y) = 0.2584 + 0.20 \cdot (0.26 + 0.36 + 0.22) + 0.36 \cdot (0.37 + 0.22) + 0.20 \cdot 0.22 =0.688. $

Thank you for your time.

Comment: look right to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.   There appear to be some typos.  Recheck your figures.

> (a) $P(X = Y )= 0.20 \cdot 0.15 + 0.36 \cdot 0.26 + 0.26 \cdot 0.37 + 0.18 \cdot0.22 = 0.2584.$

(a) $P(X = Y )= 0.20 \cdot 0.15 + 0.36 \cdot 0.26 + 0.26 \cdot 0.37 + 0.18 \cdot0.22 = 0.25\mathbf 94.$

Have not

> (b) $ P(X ≤ Y )= P( X = Y) + P (x < y) = 0.2584 + 0.20 \cdot (0.26 + 0.36 + 0.22) + 0.36 \cdot (0.37 + 0.22) + 0.20 \cdot 0.22 =0.688. $

$ P(X ≤ Y )= P( X = Y) + P (x < y) = 0.25\mathbf 94 + 0.20 \cdot (0.26 + 0.3\mathbf 7 + 0.22) + 0.36 \cdot (0.37 + 0.22) + 0.2\mathbf 6 \cdot 0.22 =0.6\mathbf{99}$